# Não consigo retornar os valores atribuídos as variáveis

Tags: python, orientação-a-objetos, funções, python-kivy

Sou leigo me programação e resolvi iniciar uma programa em python pra usar como ferramenta em um jogo
bom, o codigo até então é esse:

```
def tempo (temp):
total=temp*quant
dias=total//(24*60*60)
var1=total-(dias*(24*60*60))
horas=var1//(60*60)
var2=var1-(horas*(60*60))
minu=var2//60
seg=var2-(minu*60)
print('O tempo é de %d dias, %d horas, %d minutos e %d segundos'%(dias,horas,minu,seg))

def velocidade(nome,nivel):
time = nome * (2/3)/1.06**nivel
tempo(time)

def custo (mad,arg,fer,faz):
mad_final= mad * quant
arg_final= arg * quant
fer_final=fer * quant
faz_final=faz * quant
print('O custo será de %d de maidera, %d argila e %d de ferro!\n %d de população na fazenda'%(mad_final,arg_final,fer_final,faz_final))


# Custos tempo
Lanceiro=1020
Espadachim=1500
Barbaro=1320
Arqueiro=1800
Explorador=900
Cavalaria_leve=1800
Arqueiro_cavalo=2700
Cavalaria_pesada=3600
Ariete=4800
Catapulta=7200

# Custo recursos

Lan=(50,30,10,1)
Esp=(30,30,70,1)
Bar=(60,30,40,1)
Arq=(100,30,60,1)
Exp=(50,50,20,2)
Leve=(125,100,250,4)
Arq_cav=(250,100,150,5)
Pesada=(200,150,600,6)
Ari=(300,200,200,5)
Cat=(320,400,100,8)

# Começo

print('###########################\n# O que você deseja calcular? #\n###########################')
var=int(input ('1 - Tempo de recrutamento \n2 - Custo de recursos\n3 - Todas as anteriores\n'))
#Recrutamento
if var == 1 :
    print('Qual tropar?\n')
    trop= int(input ('1 - Lanceiro\n2 - Espadachin\n3 - Barbaro\n4 - Arqueiro\n5 - Explorador\n6 - Cavalaria leve\n7 - Arqueiro a cavalo\n8 - Cavalaria pesada \n9 - Ariete\n10 - Catapulta\n '))
    quant=int(input ('Qual a quantidade?\n'))
#Quartel
    if (1<=trop<=4):
        nivel=int(input('Nivel do Quartel:\n'))
        if trop==1:
            velocidade(Lanceiro,nivel)
        elif trop==2:
            velocidade(Espadachim,nivel)
        elif trop==3:
            velocidade(Barbaro,nivel)
        elif trop==4:
            velocidade(Arqueiro,nivel)
#Estabulo
    elif(4<trop<=8):
        nivel=int(input('Nivel do Estabulo:\n'))
        if trop==5:
            velocidade(Explorador,nivel)
        elif trop==6:
            velocidade(Cavalaria_leve,nivel)
        elif trop==7:
            velocidade(Arqueiro_cavalo,nivel)
        elif trop==8:
            velocidade(Cavalaria_pesada,nivel)
#Oficina
    elif(9<=trop<=10):
        nivel=int(input('Nivel do Oficina:\n'))
        if trop==9:
            velocidade(Ariete,nivel)
        elif trop==10:
            velocidade(Catapulta,nivel)
#Custo
elif var==2:
    print('Qual tropar?\n')
    trop= int(input ('1 - Lanceiro\n2 - Espadachin\n3 - Barbaro\n4 - Arqueiro\n5 - Explorador\n6 - Cavalaria leve\n7 - Arqueiro a cavalo\n8 - Cavalaria pesada \n9 - Ariete\n10 - Catapulta\n '))
    quant=int(input ('Qual a quantidade?\n'))
    #Quartel
    if (1<=trop<=4):
    if trop==1:
        custo(Lan)
```

Meu problema é na função custo, pois não consigo fazer com que os valores atribuidos a variavel "Lan" por exemplos funcionem dentro da função, de que forma poderia resolver esse problema?

Comment: Por favor, corrija a indentação do código e descreva o que cada parte deveria fazer. Você já estou construção de algoritmos antes de tentar programar em alguma linguagem? Se não, deveria antes de qualquer coisa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema está no número de argumentos da função custo. Observe o código abaixo:

```
def teste(a,b):
    print(a)
    print(b)

if __name__ == "__main__": #O código abaixo será executado caso o programa seja executado
    tupla = [1, 2]
    teste(tupla)
```

Esse programa gera a seguinte exceção,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in <module>
TypeError: teste() missing 1 required positional argument: 'b'
```

que em português traduz-se, a grosso modo, para `teste() tem um argumento posicional faltando: 'b'`. Isso significa que na chamada da função teste, o programa atribui `a = tupla`, mas não teve nada para atribuir à `b`.

Há algumas formas de corrigir a chamada da função `teste(tupla)`:

- Acessando as posições da tupla na chamada: `teste(tupla[0], tupla[1])`
- Desempacotando a tupla: `teste(*tupla)`

---

No seu exemplo, bastaria substituir:

```
if trop==1:
    custo(Lan)
```

por

```
if trop==1:
    custo(*Lan)
```

ou por

```
if trop==1:
    custo(Lan[0], Lan[1], Lan[2], Lan[3])
```

que o programa funcionaria.

---

Obs: as linhas

```
if (1<=trop<=4):
if trop==1:
    custo(Lan)
```

parecem conter erros de sintaxe (está sem a identação extra após na linha abaixo do if) e de lógica.

Comment: Esse ficou quando passei aqui pro site, fiz a conta hoje!